# Js: How to access an object of the parent class in a subclass function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, parent-child, subclass, parent

Im learning Javascript at the moment and now Im facing huge problems to adapt to the prototype-based programming in Js. I posted the code of my problem below:

```
    //This is my parent class
    var Entity = function(id)
    {
       this.self = 
       {
          x:250,
          y:250,
          id:id,
       }
    }

    //This is the subclass
    var Player = function(id)
    {  
       Entity.call(this, id);  

       this.updatePosition = function()
       {
          // HOW DO I ACCESS "self" from the parent class here?
          // I want to change the x and y variables from the self object
       }
    }

    Player.prototype = Object.create(Entity.prototype);
    Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
```

I would be happy if someone could help me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given this statement `Entity.call(this, id);` inside the `Entity` function `this` refers to the newly created `Player` instance which means that inside the `updatePosition` function you can access `x` and `y` using `this.self.x` and `this.self.y`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is your instance, and your `Player` class inherits all the properties from `Entity` including `.self`. You'd just access the coordinates as `this.self.x` and `this.self.y`; however you should reconsider why you need that `self` object at all and why you don't put its properties directly on the instance.